# RC and LC Circuits equations

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, inductor

I'm currently doing RC and LC circuit at university and I am missing a really huge point. My question might seem silly but I would really appreciate clarification. So,  for an RC circuit it seems like we can use two different equations to find voltage $$v=v(0)+{1/C}\ \int_0^t\!i\ dt$$ $$v=V_s+V_s\ e^{-t/RC} $$ 
 and two different equations to find current $$ i=C\ dv/dt $$ $$i={(V_{s}e^{-t/RC})/R}$$

\$v\$ being Transient Voltage, \$C\$ being Capacitance, \$t\$ being Time, \$i\$ being Transient Current, \$V_s\$ being Source Voltage, \$R\$ being Circuit Resistance.

My question is, can both equations in each case be used interchangeably depending on the given variables? Or do they have to be used in different specific situations? or is only one of them that gets used for practical purposes while the other is just some kind of theoretic derivation of the  first? Thanks.

Comment: Not when one of them is wrong.

Comment: not sure, since no circuit is shown making it difficult to know exactly what "\$ V_s \$" is but suspect that the second equation should be $$ v(t) = V_s - V_s\ e^{-t/RC} $$ for \$ t \ge 0 \$ and assuming \$ v(0) = 0 \$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first two(**v** and **i**),which includes derivation and integration, are derived from mesh and nodal equations applying Kirchhoff's Voltage Law and Kirchhoff's Current Law known as KVL and KCL.

The bottom two(**v** and **i**) are transient responses that are derived using the **τ**(tau) value of series RLC circuit.

In your example, there is a single source and a single capacitor. Therefore you can use any of those four equations.

However, sometimes the circuits cannot be simplified into single elements. 
The resistance value in 1/RC is the equivalent resistance. Likewise the R value in L/R ,which is the parameter of parallel RLC circuit, is the equivalent resistance.

So, you can interchangebly use those equations if the circuit is parallel or series.
It is easier to use transient response equations since they are much faster to write and calculate. Applying mesh equations are more time consuming. However, if the circuit is neither series nor parallel, you have to apply KVL and KCL to find the response of the circuit.

Comment: since no circuit was shown nor described, there are no mesh or node nor Kirchoff equations.  the first and third equations are only the **volt-amp characteristic** of this device we call a *"capacitor"*.  there is not much that is correct nor explanatory value in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The differential equation is the fundamental relationship between R/C/V/I. If you tell it the input signal and initial conditions, it will give the output response (after some analysis).

An exponential equation, in this context, is the response of a circuit to a specific input signal, such as a voltage source being switched on. It is the solution of the differential equation for a set of input and initial conditions.

Answer (score 0):

This is the classic RC charging situation. Seeing the circuit diagram would help us understand the operation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKcVmG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this case, the voltage across C1, V<sub>C</sub>, is initially zero. Run the "Time Domain Simulation". Two graphs will appear. One plot is the charging current, flowing thru the whole loop. The second plot is the voltage across the capacitor. Notice how the charging current is 10mA (=V<sub>S</sub>/R1=10/1000) at t=0, and falls to nearly zero at t=1 sec. Then notice how the capacitor's voltage is zero at t=0, but exponentially increases to nearly V<sub>S</sub> (10 volts) at t=1sec.